# VBA code to delete emails after x Days

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to delete all emails in my inbox that are older than 90 days. I am not able to use the auto archive since it has been disabled at my office. I have some code that does not seem to be deleting every mail that is older than 90 days. I think the issue might be with my loop. I am using Outlook 2010 with exchange 2010.

```
Private Sub RemoveEmail90()

Dim olSession As Outlook.Application, olNamespace As NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim i As Integer
Set olSession = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olSession.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Delete_Items = olInbox.Items

For i = Delete_Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    If TypeName(Delete_Items.Item(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            If DateDiff("d",now, Delete_Items.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 90 Then Delete_Items.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next

Set olSession = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to give an example of what *isn't* getting deleted which you think should be deleted.

Comment: When I run the script I am expecting. Email Older than 90 days to be deleted. When I tested the script It did in fact delete most of my emails older than 90 days but it also did not get every email older than 90 days. When I ran the scrip earlier I see email earlier than 1/18/2013 which would be older than 90 days. The scrip did infact delete most of my old email but it seems like it is jumping out of the loop too early.

Comment: Forgot to add that I am only trying to delete emails, and not calender invites or meeting request.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debug.print line to log the `TypeName` and `ReceivedTime` for each item? There may be something unexpected there...

Comment: Tim - After doing the debug this is what I see Line (1        MailItem      1/11/2013 3:55:11 PM) Maybe the issue is with my Then statement ( Then Delete_Items.Item(i).Delete) since I can see this message still in outlook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916078/vba-to-delete-outlook-messages-from-a-user-created-folder-over-certain-time-peri

Comment: I was able to fix it by tweaking the code. Now the code runs just fine. I change the "m" on line 13 to a "d" and now it is deleting all older emails. Updated code Above.

    If DateDiff("d",now, Delete_Items.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 90 Then Delete_Items.Item(i).Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by tweaking the code. Now the code runs just fine. I change the "m" on line 13 to a "d" and now it is deleting all older emails. Updated code Above.

```
If DateDiff("d",now, Delete_Items.Item(i).ReceivedTime) > 90 Then Delete_Items.Item(i).Delete
```