# How to set up rule to delete messages after 30 days in Trash in Outlook 2016 Mac Version?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server

At work using Office365, I have been struggling how to set up to delete messages after 30 days to be in Trash automatically. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Using Mac Version Outlook client.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete message after 30 days in Drafts folder using the below code:

```
Private Sub RemoveEmail90()

Dim olSession As Outlook.Application, olNamespace As NameSpace
Dim olDrafts As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim i As Integer
Set olSession = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olSession.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olDrafts = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
Set Delete_Items = olDrafts.Items

For i = Delete_Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    If TypeName(Delete_Items.item(i)) = "MailItem" Then
            If DateDiff("d", Now, Delete_Items.item(i).ReceivedTime) > 30 Then
                Delete_Items.item(i).Delete
            End If
    End If
Next

Set olSession = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Reference from:

[VBA code to delete emails after x Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482736/vba-code-to-delete-emails-after-x-days)