# How do I make Outlook purge a folder automatically when anything arrives in it?

Tags: vba, outlook

I hope it's okay to ask this kind of question. Attempting to write the code myself is completely beyond me at the moment.

I need a macro for Outlook 2007 that will permanently delete all content of the Sent Items folder whenever anything arrives in it. Is it possible? How do I set everything up so that the user doesn't ever have to click anything to run it?

I know I'm asking for a fish, and I'm embarrassed, but I really need the thing...

**edit:**

I've pasted this into the VBA editor, into a new module:

```
Public Sub EmptySentEmailFolder()

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim sentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim entryID As String

Set outApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set sentFolder = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

For i = sentFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    sentFolder.Items(i).Delete             '' Delete from mail folder
Next
Set item = Nothing
Set sentFolder = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

It's just a slightly modified version of a piece of code I found somewhere on this site deleting Deleted Items. It does delete the Sent Items folder when I run it. Could you please help me modify it in such a way that it deletes Sent Items whenever anything appears in the folder, and in such a way that the user doesn't have to click anything to run it? I need it to be a completely automated process.

**edit 2:** Please if you think there's a better tool to achieve this than VBA, don't hesitate to edit the tags and comment.

**edit 3:** I did something that works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't. And it's ridiculously complicated. I set a rule that ccs every sent email with an attachment to me. Another rule runs the following code, when an email from me arrives.

```
Sub Del(item As Outlook.MailItem)
Call EmptySentEmailFolder
End Sub
```

The thing has three behaviors, and I haven't been able to determine what triggers which behavior. Sometimes the thing does purge the Sent Items folder. Sometimes it does nothing. Sometimes the second rule gives the "operation failed" error message.

The idea of acting whenever something comes from my address is non-optimal for reasons that I'll omit for the sake of brevity. I tried to replace it with reports. I made a rule that sends a delivery report whenever I send an email. Then another rule runs the code upon receipt of the report. However, this has just one behavior: it never does anything.

Both ideas are so complicated that anything could go wrong really, and I'm having trouble debugging them. Both are non-optimal solutions too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language and don't have the application to try it out, but perhaps this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916078/vba-to-delete-outlook-messages-from-a-user-created-folder-over-certain-time-peri
Also, this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/03af0a86-54e9-4ff1-b0a6-9cc37c6e1f81/delete-mail-item-in-an-outlook-folder-with-vba

Comment: @ParrotMac Hi, thanks. We came across the same question. I've just edited my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: I'm under the impression that setting such an event listener would be done through the wizard rather than part of the code -- I believe it's  part of the 'Rules and Alerts' section.

Comment: @ParrotMac I don't think that's the case here. Usually it would work, but rules on outgoing emails don't have the "run a script" option. Also I don't want to run the macro when the message is sent, but when it arrives in the Sent Items folder. The former would probably be useless because it would probably clean up all the messages _except_ the one that's just been sent. What I've managed to do is to run a rule permanently deleting messages, but I had to run it by hand. It seems that rules can only be triggered automatically when a message is sent or received (but received in the Inbox folder.)

Comment: [This post](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/#comment-175867) gives me hope it might be possible to do with a piece of code.

Comment: Your question reads as though you do not want sent emails saved in Sent Items.  For Outlook 2003, select Tools then Options then Preferences then E-Mail Options then untick "Save copies of messages in Sent Items folder".  For Outlook 2007 (and I assume later) visit http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-where-sent-e-mail-messages-are-saved-HA010164216.aspx.

Comment: @Tony Hi, not really. My problem is unfortunately more complicated. You can see it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/628528/how-do-i-force-a-scanner-not-to-leave-messages-in-sent-items-in-outlook).

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an acceptable solution?  Sorry its late but my copy of Outlook was broken.

When you enter the Outlook VB Editor, the Project Explorer will be on the left.  Click <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> if it isn't.  It will look something like this:

```
+  Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)
```

or

```
-  Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)
   +  Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
   +  Forms
   +  Modules
```

"Forms" will be missing if you do not have any user forms.  It is possible "Modules" is expanded.  Click <kbd>+</kbd>s as necessary to get "Microsoft Office Outlook Objects" expanded:

```
-  Project1 (VbaProject.OTM)
   -  Microsoft Office Outlook Objects
        ThisOutlookSession
   +  Forms
   +  Modules
```

Click <kbd>ThisOutlookSession</kbd>.  The module area will turn white unless you have already used this code area.  This area is like a module but have additional privileges.  Copy this code to that area:

```
Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

  ' This event routine is called automatically when a user has completed log in.

  Dim sentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim entryID As String
  Dim i As Long

  Set sentFolder = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
                        GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

  For i = sentFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    sentFolder.Items(i).Delete             ' Move to Deleted Items
  Next

  Set sentFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have taken your code, tidied it up a little and placed it within an event routine.  An event routine is automatically called when the appropriate event occurs.  This routine is called when the user has completed their log in.  This is not what you requested but it might be an acceptable compromise.

**Suggestion 2**

I have not tried an ItemAdd event routine on the Sent Items folder before although I have used it with the Inbox.  According to my limited testing, deleting the sent item does not interfere with the sending.

This code belongs in "ThisOutlookSession".

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents MyNewItems As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_MAPILogonComplete()

  Dim NS As NameSpace

  Set NS = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

  With NS
    Set MyNewItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
  End With

End Sub
Private Sub myNewItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

  Debug.Print "--------------------"
  Debug.Print "Item added to Sent folder"
  Debug.Print "Subject: " & Item.Subject
  Item.Delete             ' Move to Deleted Items
  Debug.Print "Moved to Deleted Items"

End Sub
```

The Debug.Print statements show you have limited access to the sent item.  If you try to access more sensitive properties, you will trigger a warning to the user that a macro is assessing emails.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So this solution pretty much requires a regular user to restart Outlook, right? I'm not sure this will work. If I could expect the users to follow instructions, I could just tell them to delete the mail in Sent Items manually each time they send a scan. I've already told them to that and some do, but not all. And the attachments left can contain sensitive information. They just shouldn't hang in there for everyone to see. If users need to restart outlook (or relogon) some will keep forgetting about that too, for sure...

Comment: I had not realised the emails contained sensitive information. I assumed you just wanted them deleted without any bother to the user. You could attach the delete to another event that will happen more frequently.

Comment: I have added a second suggestion to my answer which may better meet your requirements.